# How to update a value inside an array in graphql

Tags: graphql

I have this structure:

```
    "data": {
        "item": {
            "id": "1",
            "options": [
                {
                    "label": "Top",
                    "specs": [
                        {
                            "label": "Left",
                            "value": "0"
                        },
                        {
                            "label": "Right",
                            "value": "1000"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "label": "Bottom",
                    "specs": [
                        {
                            "label": "Left",
                            "value": "11"
                        },
                        {
                            "label": "Right",
                            "value": "1"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

And trying to update the value of: item -> options (label 'Top') -> specs (label 'Right') -> value.

What query should I write to access the value inside those arrays?

Answer (score 0):

GraphQL queries are not bi-directional. If you want to change data you must use mutations.

I recommend to read the specifications

[GraphQL Specs](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/)